# Stringindexoutofboundsexception while decrypting using AES

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am using AES as an encryption technique. While decrypting my encrypted string I am facing this `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException String index out of range : -3`. Can you tell me why am I facing this? is it related `BASE64` encoding that I used?

**Code for decryption**:

```
Key key = generateKey();
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
String salt = "some salt";
String dValue = null;
String valueToDecrypt = encryptedData;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    byte[] decordedValue = Base64.decodeBase64(valueToDecrypt);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    dValue = new String(decValue).substring(salt.length());
    valueToDecrypt = dValue;
}
```

**Code for Encryption** :

```
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    String salt = "some salt";
    String valueToEnc = null;
    String eValue = Data;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        valueToEnc = salt + eValue;
        byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT));
        eValue =new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encValue));
    }
```

**Reference** : http://www.digizol.com/2009/10/java-encrypt-decrypt-jce-salt.html

Comment: Well where *exactly* is the exception thrown? Note that using the string constructor with no charset is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Exception is thrown while decoding using Base64. Where shall I add the charset to avoid this issue?

Comment: Hang on - why are you iterating twice at all? Do you *really* have double-encrypted data, with a base64 encoding applied each time as well? That seems very odd... especially as you're not re-initializing `c` between iterations. What does your encrypting code look like?

Comment: this is my encrypting code :
Key key = generateKey();
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
String salt = "this is salt";
String valueToEnc = null;
String eValue = Data;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
valueToEnc = salt + eValue;
byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT));
eValue =new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encValue));
}

Comment: Don't add it as a comment - edit your question. (And explain *why* you think it's worth encrypting twice.)